# Apyori, outputting a rule with more than two items isn't working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apriori

I'm a total python noob and programming beginner, but I'm trying to analyse some fictional Data using apyori in python for school.
I didn't write most of this program myself, I got it from a Jupyter Notebook my teacher gave me and I understand most of it, except for the actual creation of the data frame we output at the end.

My biggest issue is this though:
If I output the entire rule for one of the rows in my data frame, with

```
print(association_results[0])
```

I get this output:

> RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'Spiderman 3', 'Moana', 'Tomb Rider'}), support=0.007199040127982935, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'Moana', 'Tomb Rider'}), items_add=frozenset({'Spiderman 3'}), confidence=0.20300751879699247, lift=3.0825089038385434)])

If I understand it correctly that should essentially mean "When someone buys Moana and Tomb Rider they're likely to also buy Spiderman 3", however in my Database at the end I only get the output "When someone buys Moana they're likely to also buy Spiderman 3".

That happens for multiple rows in my data frame and I couldn't find an example online of anyone having a rule including two items as the "when", so I don't understand how I can output both movies into the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd  
from apyori import apriori

movie_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\XY\Desktop\movie_dataset.csv", header = None) #import data
num_records = len(movie_data)

#########
records = []  
for i in range(0, num_records):  
    records.append([str(movie_data.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 20)])

for i, j in enumerate(records): # deletes empty items out of the data frame (this was an issue before)
    while 'nan' in records[i]:  # because it output "when Green Lantern is bought, nothing is bought as well)
        records[i].remove('nan')

association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.0053, min_confidence=0.20, min_lift=3, min_length=2)
association_results = list(association_rules) 

results = []
for item in association_results:
    
    # first index of the inner list
    # Contains base item and add item
    pair = item[0] 
    items = [x for x in pair]
    
    value0 = str(items[0])
    value1 = str(items[1])

    #second index of the inner list
    value2 = str(item[1])[:7]

    #third index of the list located at 0th
    #of the third index of the inner list

    value3 = str(item[2][0][2])[:7]
    value4 = str(item[2][0][3])[:7]
    
    rows = (value0, value1,value2,value3,value4)
    results.append(rows)
    
labels = ['When bought','Likely bought as well','Support','Confidence','Lift']
movie_suggestion = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns = labels)

print(movie_suggestion)
```

The output looks like this:

||  When bought|    Likely bought as well|  Support| Confidence|     Lift|
|----|-------------|-------------------------|---------|-----------|---------|
|0   |  Red Sparrow|            Green Lantern|  0.00573|    0.30069|  0.30069|
|1   |Green Lantern|                Star Wars|  0.00586|    0.37288|  0.37288|
|2   |Kung Fu Panda|                  Jumanji|  0.01599|    0.32345|  0.32345|
|3   | Wonder Woman|                  Jumanji|  0.00533|    0.37735|  0.37735|
|4   |  Spiderman 3|    The Spy Who Dumped Me|  0.00799|    0.27149|  0.27149|
|5   |        Moana|              Spiderman 3|  0.00533|    0.23255|  0.23255|
etc.

Instead of:
||  When bought|    Likely bought as well|  Support| Confidence|     Lift|
|----|-------------|-------------------------|---------|-----------|---------|
|0   |  Red Sparrow|            Green Lantern|  0.00573|    0.30069|  0.30069|
|1   |Green Lantern|                Star Wars|  0.00586|    0.37288|  0.37288|
|2   |Kung Fu Panda|                  Jumanji|  0.01599|    0.32345|  0.32345|
|3   | Wonder Woman|                  Jumanji|  0.00533|    0.37735|  0.37735|
|4   |  Spiderman 3|    The Spy Who Dumped Me|  0.00799|    0.27149|  0.27149|
|5   |Moana, Tomb Rider|                Spiderman 3|  0.00533|    0.23255|  0.23255|

I tried looking at all the variables to try to understand the data frame creation to figure out how to get the output i want, but i don't understand it and like I said didn't find anything matching my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized the table at the end of my question did not work as intended...
**BUT** I figured out a semi-acceptable answer for now.
Using string slicing for value0 and value1 like this:

```
value0 = str(item[2][0][0])[11:-2]
value1 = str(item[2][0][1])[11:-2]
```

And the output looks like this (didnt include confidence, support and lift for this):
|When bought          |Likely bought as well|
|----------:          |--------------------:|
|'Intern','Tomb Rider'|'World War Z'        |
and so on

okay in the preview the tables work, but on the post they don't, hope it's still readable